# Is it safe to use the Structure dereference(->) operator on the result of std::atomic::load

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Whilst trying to work with std atomic pointer, I ran into the following. Say I do this:

```
std::atomic<std::string*> myString;
// <do fancy stuff with the string... also on other threads>

//A can I do this?
myString.load()->size()

//B can I do this?
char myFifthChar = *(myString.load()->c_str() + 5);

//C can I do this?
char myCharArray[255];
strcpy(myCharArray, myString.load()->c_str());
```

I'm pretty sure C is illegal because myString might be deleted in the meantime.

However I'm unsure about A and B. I suppose they are illegal since the pointer might be deferenced whilst performing the read operation.

However if this is the case, how can you ever read from an atomic pointer that might be deleted. Since the load is 1 step, and the reading of the data is 1 step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been mentioned that your approach is risky business. Here is what you may want to consider instead: Use `std::shared_ptr<const std::string>` with immutable values, and the `shared_ptr` [atomic_load and atomic_store](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). `std::shared_ptr` will ensure you do not access a dangling pointer, while the immutability (string does not change after construction) will guarantee that accesses to the string itself are thread-safe, as all `const` methods defined by the standard are thread-safe.

EDIT: As requested an explanation of what I mean by "risky business": If you use `std::atomic<std::string *>`, then it's easy to accidentally introduce race conditions, e.g.

```
// Data
std::atomic<std::string *> str(new std::string("foo"));

// Thread 1
std::cout << *str.load();

// Thread 2
*str.load() = "bar"; // race condition with read access in thread 1

// Thread 2 (another attempt using immutable instances)
auto newStr = new std::string("bar");
auto oldStr = str.exchange(newStr);
delete oldStr;  /* race condition with read access in thread 1
                   because thread 1 may have performed load() before
                   the exchange became visible to it, and may not
                   be finished using the old object. */
```

Note that this has nothing to do with `operator <<`, even just calling `size()` on the string in thread 1 would lead to the race condition.

In practice, one may see "fixes" like adding a `sleep` before the `delete` in the update with immutable strings, so that thread 1 has enough time to finish its business with the old pointer. Although this may work *most of the time* in a particular implementation, it does not introduce a true ordering (a *happens-before* relation, in C++ standardese) and therefore is not a correct rsp. portable solution.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution:) Thank you very much:)

Comment: Could you maybe add a brief explanation as to why it's risky business? That way I can approve your answer. And future readers can enjoy the pleasure of both learning why it's illegal and getting handed a viable alternative:).

Answer (score 4):

```
// A can I do this?
myString.load()->size()
```

Yes you *can*, but you do have a race condition if something else might be mutating or destructing/deallocating the `string` to which the snapshot of `myString` you received points.  In other words, the situation after atomically retrieving the pointer is the same as for any `std::string` object to which multiple threads might have pointers, except that...

There is the question of whether the atomic `load` guarantees some particular construction/change to the `string` - perhaps performed by whichever thread updated `myString` to point to the particular `string` instance you've `load`ed a pointer to - will be visible to you.  The default is to ensure this, but you might want to [read over this explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) of the `memory_order` parameter to `load()`.  Note that *not* explicitly asking for memory synchronisation does *not* keep you safe from mutating/destruction by other threads.

So, say `myString()` is pointed successively at `string`'s `a`, `b` then `c`, and your code retrieves `&b`... as long as the `string` `b` isn't mutated or destructed/deallocated while you're calling `size()`, you're ok.  It doesn't matter that `myString()` might be updated to point to `c` before/during/after your call to `b`'s `.size()`.

Taking a step back, it can be tricky for the program to know how long after you call `load()` you might try to dereference the pointer, and if the `b` object is to later be mutated or destructed/deallocated, the kind of call you propose doesn't cooperate in any synchronisation around that later mutation/destruction.  You can obviously add such coordination in myriad ways (e.g. some other atomic counter/flag, notifying the would-be modifier/destructor/deleter using a condition variable...), or you might decide to accept such a race condition sometimes (e.g. perhaps if `b` is known to be one of the newest entries in a generously sized LRU cache).

If you're doing something like cycling `myString` around a number of `static const string` instances, you don't have to worry about all the mutation/destruction stuff above (well, not unless you're accessing them before/after `main()`).

```
// B can I do this?
char myFifthChar = *(myString.load()->c_str() + 5);
```

Yes, with all the caveats above.

```
// C can I do this?
char myCharArray[255];
strcpy(myCharArray, myString.load()->c_str());
```

Yes, as above (and subject to the buffer provided being large enough).

> I'm pretty sure C is illegal because myString might be deleted in the meantime.

As above - that concern's equally valid for all the 3 uses you've mentioned, just somewhat more likely for C because copying takes more CPU cycles to complete, and rather than get garbage values back losing a race could cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: I of course meant to use structure dereferences in the question. My bad for the omission. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm pretty sure C is illegal because myString might be deleted in the
>   meantime.

The same is true of *all* of your examples. The only thing that's safe because of an atomic load is the load itself- nothing more. You are responsible for ensuring the safety of any subsequent operations on what was loaded. And in this case, there is none, so it's terribly unsafe.

The only way to load from an atomic pointer is to ensure that you own the result- like `std::shared_ptr<T>`, or have it guaranteed to live for some longer lifetime *and* that you should ban all writing.

Answer (score 2):

If another thread might modify or delete the `string` object, then all of these are illegal.

The use of `atomic` synchronises access to the pointer, but you're doing nothing to synchronise access to the object that it points to.