# How can I extract the pointer T from std::atomic<T>?

Tags: c++, stdatomic

I have a some simple class:

```
class List {
    List *next;
    int value;
};
```

And a `std::atomic<List *> Ltag`. How can I extract the actual `List *` from `Ltag`?
I tried `Ltag->value = 80` which didn't work. Casting didn't work as well.

Comment: `Ltag.load()->value = 80;`

Comment: So you have an atomic pointer to non-atomic data.  You don't need to *extract* it, just load it.  `atomic<T*>` doesn't overload `operator->` presumably so you don't forget that the store won't be an atomic operation.

Comment: Does [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069103/misunderstanding-of-atomic-structs-and-pointers) help you? Also, an important thing to remember is that with something like `std::atomic<List*>`, only the pointer address is safe from race conditions, not the pointed-to object. If multiple threads read/write to/from the pointed-to object, you'll have UB.

Comment: Side note: Don't get overconfident with `atomic`. More often that not you want to protect an entire transaction, not just one part of it.

Comment: @alterigel: [Is it safe to use the Structure dereference(->) operator on the result of std::atomic::load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30121194) is closer to a duplicate, it's about using `.load()->member` on `atomic<T*>`, rather than about `atomic<node>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the conversion operator of `std::atomic`.

```
(*Ltag).value = 80;
```

Or use `load()` to get the value explicitly.

```
Ltag.load()->value = 80;
```

---

PS: You're using `std::atomic` with pointer, that means there might be data race on the pointed object.

Comment: It's worth noting that if multiple threads are doing this, you'll still have a race condition, since only the _address_ is atomic, not the object that is pointed to.

Comment: re: safety: [Is it safe to use the Structure dereference(->) operator on the result of std::atomic::load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30121194)